# Multiple Indexes in same Solr Core..?

Tags: solr, indexing

I am using Apache Solr..I have the following Scenario.. :

I have Two table in my PostGreSQL database. One is "***Cars***". Other is "**Dealers**"

Now i have a data-config file for ***Cars*** like the following :

```
<document name="offerings">
    <entity name="jc_offerings" query="select * from jc_offerings" >
        <field column="id" name="id" />
        <field column="name" name="name" />
        <field column="display_name" name="display_name" />
        <field column="extra" name="extra" />
    </entity>
</document>
```

I have a similar data--config.xml for "***Dealers***". It has the same fields as Cars : *name, extra* etc

Now in my Schema.xml , i have defined the following fields :

```
<fields>
  <field name="id" type="string"   indexed="true" />
  <field name="name" type="name"  indexed="true" />
  <field name="extra" type="extra"  indexed="true"  /> 

  <field name="CarsText" type="text_general" indexed="true" 
    stored="true" multiValued="true"/>
</fields>

<uniqueKey>id</uniqueKey>
<defaultSearchField>CarsText</defaultSearchField>
<copyField source="name" dest="CarsText"/>
<copyField source="extra" dest="CarsText"/>
```

Now i want to search like : "where name is Maruti"..So how will Solr know Whether to Search ::: Cars Field : name OR Dealer Field "name"..??

I have read to the following link : http://wiki.apache.org/solr/MultipleIndexes

But i am not able to understand how is works..??

After reading that link : I made another field in My **Cars** and **Dealers** **data-config.xml** .. Something like :

```
<field name="type" value="car" />  : in Cars date-config.xml
```

and

```
<field name="type" value="dealer" />  : in Cars date-config.xml
```

And then in Schema.xml i created a new field :

```
<field name="type" type="string"   indexed="true" stored="true" />
```

And then i queried something like :

`localhost:8983/solr/select?q=name:Maruti&fq=type:dealer`

But it dint Worked..!!

So what should i do..??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

if the fields are the same for both cars and dealers, you could use one index with an object defined like so:

```
<fields>
  <field name="id" type="string"   indexed="true" stored="true"/>
  <field name="name" type="name"  indexed="true" stored="true" />
  <field name="extra" type="extra"  indexed="true" stored="true" /> 
  <field name="description_text" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true"/>
  <field name="type" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" />
</fields>
```

this will work for both cars and dealers (so you don't need to have 2 indexes) and you'll use the "type" field to sort out if you want a "dealer" or a "car" (i'm using the same system to filter out similar types of objects with only a minor "semanthical" difference)

also you'll need to add stored="true" to the fields you want to retrieve, or you'll be only able to use them for searching (hence that index="true")

Comment: did u read my question carefully..??..i tld that i already did this..but the fact is : its not working..when ever i query for the type, nothing comes up in the result..What should i do ??

Comment: i read your question carefully, even if it's not in perfect english. and as far as i can understand, you still have multiple indexes. you should merge everything into a single index, following my examples. your field "type" also has 2 default values, split between the 2 indexes. also, when you query for "Maruti" and nothing else, what's the output?

Comment: in your example : u mentioned "type" field..now if you write "fq=type:Samuele" ..what comes up..??..u need to define type somewhere..like "car" OR "dealer"..and SOLR should be able to know how many types are available..how did you achieved that..??

Comment: i simply treat that field as any other field, and i populate it at index time. you have a postgres db right? so you know if you're pulling a "car" item or a "dealer" item. you can easily pass the value to solr from there (or write a plugin like i did, but i needed to manage bigger and more complex data)

Comment: I do not have a "type" like field in my Table..My "cars" and "articles" are in different tables.. "select * from articles" give articles..and similarly for "cars"..How to make solr know whether i want to search on Articles OR Cars..??..Please explain with an example..!!

Comment: What @Samuele Mattiuzzo is suggesting is that you add a type field to your Solr schema. When adding rows to your index from "cars" you insert with type "car". When adding rows to your index from "dealers" you insert with type "dealer". Then to query one or the other you would do ?q=*:*&fq=type:car or ?q=*:*&fq=type:dealer . Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi david..the solution you suggested might be good..but the fact is : i am fetching rows from the PostgreSQL table , that does not have a TYPE Field defined..so how will i put TYPE = DEALERS, when indexing..??..thats what i was asking..!!

Comment: You have 2 options again. Index the tables separately, so you can post the "type" field statically. Or, write your custom plugin that retrieves the current result's table name and post it to solr (see http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrPlugins#Building_Plugins for plugin developing.) I'd suggest the first option, tho, seems easier.

Answer (score 2):

Adding a default value to the type field will ensure the type value being set to `cars|dealer`.

You will have to index the sources separately. Then use copy field and you can easily filter on either `cars|dealer`.

This does seem a bit tricky and is not explained well in the muti-indexes link referred to above.