# what is SOLR multicore exactly

Tags: solr, solrnet

In SOLR, what is multicore?

Is it a way to create multiple tables (inside a single solr app) with their own set of schema files, or is it about creating different databases (inside a single solr app)?

If we want to create multiple tables (with their respective schema.xml files) for solr web app then what is the best way to do this, or how can we achieve this in SOLR?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Solr Multicore is basically a set up for allowing Solr to host multiple cores.
These Cores which would host a complete different set of unrelated entities.
You can have a separate Core for each table as well.

For e.g. If you have collections for Documents, People, Stocks which are completely unrelated entities you would want to host then in different collections

Multicore setup would allow you to

1. Host unrelated entities separately so that they don't impact each other
2. Having a different configuration for each core with different behavior
3. Performing activities on each core differently (Update data, Load, Reload, Replication)
4. keep the size of the core in check and configure caching accordingly

Comment: thank you for answering my query. but i havent found answer for my last question. that is how to create multiple tables in a single solr webapp ?.

Comment: Just configure a Single core with all the fields and index data into it. You can add a fixed field to identify the document type. If using DIH check handling with multiple Entities.

Comment: Hi Jayendra, thanks for reply. But if i want to upload multiple tables like 5 master tables from my database into solr, in this case i cannot club them in to single core. So just wanted to know how can we create multiple tables in a single solr web app.

Comment: Please see Running Multiple Indexes -http://wiki.apache.org/solr/MultipleIndexes and this previous question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9564812/multiple-indexes-in-same-solr-core

Comment: Can't a collection have multiple cores? I see here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17044640/solr-collection-vs-cores this : `So basically a Collection (Logical group) has multiple cores (physical indexes).`.